# Elassandra "action_request_validation_exception"

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, cassandra

```
Elasticsearch DEBUG: 2019-09-23T09:23:39Z
  starting request {
    "method": "HEAD",
    "castExists": true,
    "path": "/my_keyspace",
    "query": {}
  }


Elasticsearch TRACE: 2019-09-23T09:23:39Z
  -> HEAD http://192.168.99.100:9200/my_keyspace

  <- 200


Elasticsearch DEBUG: 2019-09-23T09:23:39Z
  Request complete

Elasticsearch DEBUG: 2019-09-23T09:23:39Z
  starting request {
    "method": "PUT",
    "path": "/my_keyspace/_mapping",
    "body": {
      "discover": ".*",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "summary": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "company": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    },
    "query": {
      "type": "job"
    }
  }


Elasticsearch TRACE: 2019-09-23T09:23:39Z
  -> PUT http://192.168.99.100:9200/my_keyspace/_mapping?type=job
  {
    "discover": ".*",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "summary": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "company": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
  <- 400
  {
    "error": {
      "root_cause": [
        {
          "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
          "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: my_keyspace.job table does not exists;"
        }
      ],
      "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
      "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: my_keyspace.job table does not exists;"
    },
    "status": 400
  }

Elasticsearch DEBUG: 2019-09-23T09:23:39Z
  Request complete

Unhandled rejection Error: [action_request_validation_exception] Validation Failed: 1: my_keyspace.job table does not exists;
    at respond (\project\root\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:349:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (\project\root\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:306:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (\project\root\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\connectors\http.js:173:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (\project\root\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4929:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

I am attempting to use `masumsoft/express-cassandra` to connect to the latest Elassandra at `strapdata/elassandra`. The dialog seems to be valid however connecting results in an unexpected error, any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to rename the "Job" model as it is a reserved keyword in Elasticsearch/Cassandra.